# Get either HH:mm:ss, mm:ss regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string where I would like to extract a time stamp. The time stamp could be anywhere in the string, and the timestamp could be different lengths. Think youtube video time stamping.

Here is an example

> What would you change for education from your 27:19:45 experience k-12? #change'

I would like to extract 27:19:45. However other strings could contain only MM:SS

The regex I could come up with was

```js
const timeRegex = /(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)/gm;
```

When I run this regex it also picks up the 12 in the k-12 part of the string which I don't want.

Sorry I removed the seconds part. If it were just seconds it would have 0:12

Comment: _"which I don't want."_ Why not? Your string could contain ss. Regex doesn't understand semantic. How could it find out the meaning of a two digit number? If I correctly understand all three string should match: `12:12:12`, `12:12`, `12`

Comment: 27:19:45 is not a valid `HH:mm:ss`

Comment: @MinusFour: it's valid on Venus.

Comment: Clarified. Forget about the seconds, it would be 0:12 if just 12 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
(?<!\S)(?:(?:(\d{1,2}):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)(?!\S)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/EFprgS/2).

In your expression, you need to make `MM` part compulsory.

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S                       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \d{1,2}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 2 times
                                 (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-5]?                   any character of: '0' to '5' (optional
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-5]?                   any character of: '0' to '5' (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S                       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: The title is _"Get either HH:mm:ss, mm:ss, ss regex"_. `24` is `ss` and a valid match

Comment: There's also the matter of how many hours you can actually upload in a video to youtube, could it be that more than 99 hours is possible? 27 hours already feels wrong but I am not entirely sure... Maybe it should allow for any number of hours.

Comment: I understand, let it be whitespace-restricted then.

Comment: But the sentence could end after the timestamp with punctuation. The timestamp could be in quotes or parenthesis.

Comment: @jabaa Can't see any in the example string.

Comment: It's an example string. Usually examples don't show all possible cases. In the examples of [RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986)  (URI specification) you don't see all possible URIs.

Comment: @jabaa Let OP speak up then.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know only OP is allowed to ask questions or give comments.

Answer (score 1):

This one should work:

```
const timeRegex = /\d\d:\d\d(:\d\d)?/gm
```

Or, ff the numbers between the colons can be one or two:

```
const timeRegex = /\d\d?:\d\d?(:\d\d?)?/gm
```

Test:

```
s = "What would you change for education from your 27:09:02 experience k-12? #change'"
-> "What would you change for education from your 27:09:02 experience k-12? #change'"
s.match(/\d\d?:\d\d?(:\d\d?)?/gm)
-> ["27:09:02"]
s = "What would you change for education from your 27:09 experience k-12? #change'"
-> "What would you change for education from your 27:09 experience k-12? #change'"
s.match(/\d\d?:\d\d?(:\d\d?)?/gm)
-> ["27:09"]
s = "What would you change for education from your experience k-12? #change'"
-> "What would you change for education from your experience k-12? #change'"
s.match(/\d\d?:\d\d?(:\d\d?)?/gm)
-> null
```

Comment: The title is _"Get either HH:mm:ss, mm:ss, ss regex"_. `24` is `ss` and a valid match

Answer (score 1):

You can use positive lookahead and positive lookbehind and select only if there is `\s` on both the side of the time.

```js
const str =
  "What would you change for education from your 27:19:45 and 12:12 and 11 experience k-12? #change";

const result = str.match(/(?<=\s)(\d\d:?)+(?=\s)/g);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: What about `"Let's meet at 12:12:12!!!"`? Isn't `12:12:12` a valid timestamp in this case?

Comment: Then how would you differentiate between `k-12` and `12`. Since I was restricting the cases

Comment: Exactly. Why would you even differentiate? How do you know the 12 in k-12 isn't the number of seconds. The question is completely unclear and has at least one wrong answer.